# How to draw images on labels

Tags: python, image, label, draw

I am currently trying to draw qr codes on my labels (pylabels library). I am able to create the qr code images using the qrcode library. However, I am a bit lost with how I actually draw the images on the labels.

I used the sample code from https://github.com/bcbnz/pylabels/blob/1.2.1/demos/basic.py

I tried to use all the methods offered by shapes.Drawing but haven't had any success.

I went through the reportlab documentation but doesn't really understand how I get it to work.

```py
def draw_label(label, width, height, obj):
    # Just convert the object to a string and print this at the bottom left of
    # the label.

    config = obj.get('config')

    label.add(shapes.String(2, 2, f'{config.get("code")}', fontName="Helvetica", fontSize=10))

    label.add(shapes.Drawing.drawOn(label, obj.get('image'), 100, 100))



def create_labels():
    specs = labels.Specification(210, 297, 4, 5, 45, 45, corner_radius=1)
    sheet = labels.Sheet(specs, draw_label, border=True)

    for num in range(10000, 10020):
        setup_dict = {
            'setup': 'setup-config',
            'code': num,
        }

        qr = qrcode.QRCode(
            version=1,
            error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_H,
            box_size=15,
            border=5,
        )

        # Add JSON encoded data to qr code
        qr.add_data(json.dumps(setup_dict))
        qr.make(fit=True)

        qr_code = {
            'config': setup_dict,
            'image': qr.make_image(fill_color="black", back_color="white"),
        }

        sheet.add_label(qr_code)

        sheet.save('/qr_codes.pdf')
```

Would be very much appreciated, if anyone could give me an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. I was so confused, that I did not see the obvious. Below is what you need, if you run into the same issue.

```
from reportlab.graphics.shapes import Image

label.add(Image(25, 42, 80, 80, obj.get('image')))
```